# Getting an Illegal String Offset by using $_Get if a string isn't defined

Tags: php, string

I've done some digging on here but seems this issue has more to do with an Array. I'm using this snippet of code to check and see if a form has passed data. If it hasn't it can grab data from the url and do the same thing.

In most cases the form data will be passed but for links I need to go this route.

```
if(!$season['sid']){
    $season['sid']=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["series"]);
}
if(!$season['id']){
    $season['id']=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["season"]);
}
if(!$team['id']){
    $team['id']=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["team"]);
}
$check=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT uid FROM series WHERE id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $season['sid'])."'");
$check=mysqli_fetch_array($check);

if($check['uid'] <> $_COOKIE['tid']){
error("You do not have permission to manage this series.");
}
```

I keep getting the error I do not have permission. If I pass the data via the form I have no issue.

Here is the data my error_log dumps..

```
[27-Jun-2017 21:06:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'sid' in /home/*/public_html/seriesmanager.php on line 876
[27-Jun-2017 21:06:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'id' in /home/*/public_html/seriesmanager.php on line 879
[27-Jun-2017 21:06:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'id' in /home/*/public_html/seriesmanager.php on line 882
[27-Jun-2017 21:06:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'sid' in /home/*/public_html/seriesmanager.php on line 885
```

If there's any way I can make this question better I am open to feedback.
Thank you!

Comment: That's what `isset()` is used for.

Comment: you escape  `$season['sid']` twice, which may have unexpected results

Comment: Illegal string offset usually means that you are trying to use something like a string variable as an array. Is ```$season``` and ```$team``` an array?

Comment: This might be why but didn't really think it would play a factor. Because `isset()` doesn't work either. The strings are technically passed via a switch. So just above the code is
`function players($team,$mes,$season){
global $config;
global $connection;`

Answer (score 0):

Using isset your code would look like this:

```
if(!isset($season['sid'])){
    $season['sid']=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["series"]);
}
if(!isset($season['id'])){
    $season['id']=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["season"]);
}
if(!isset($team['id'])){
    $team['id']=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["team"]);
}
```

And say goodbye to *unset* warnings.